# Log4j2 лог не записывается файл

Tags: java, log4j2

Начал разбираться с логгером Log4j2 и нашел на одном сайте вот такую конфигурацию файла `log4j2.properties` (находится по пути `/src/main/resources/`), которая должна настроить логгер на одновременную запись и в консоль, и в файл:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/logs.txt
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=guru.springframework.blog.log4j2properties
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

При запуске программы лог начинает записываться в консоль. Создается файл `logs.txt`, но в него ничего не записывается. Запускаю собранный .jar'ник из консоли.

---

Почему лог не записывается в файл, а записывается только в консоль и как это исправить?

---

**UPD_0:**

Для примера, класс `Main` из моего проекта:

```
public class Main {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException, UnknownHostException {
        log.info("This is minimal, complete, and verifiable example!");
    }
}
```

Maven-зависимости:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57983/discussion-on-question-by-rostislav-dugin-log4j2----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допишите строку в файл конфигурации:

```
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
```